# NgxTypeAhead throws list.filter is not a function within its code

Tags: typescript, typeahead.js, angular13

I have the following code from here:

Simple Typeahead with Local Data List
In the component template, add the following Input form field control with ngxTypeahead directives and some other required attribute properties.

[Type Ahead Example](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-simple-typeahead-autocomplete-suggestion-search-implementation-in-angular-6-applications/)

What's failing is this:

```
    createListSource(list, query) {
        const sanitizedQuery = this.taCaseSensitive ? query : query.toLowerCase();
        const fieldsToExtract = this.taListItemField;
        return of(list.filter((item) => {
            return resolveItemValue(item, fieldsToExtract, this.taCaseSensitive).includes(sanitizedQuery);
        }));
    }
```

It's found in line 332 in ngx-typeahead.js

This is the code to help you from searching:

```
<input [value]="search1"
        ngxTypeahead
        [taList]="myLocalList" 
        (taSelected)="selectedStatic($event)">
```

[taList]: Items data list which will populate when a user types.

(taSelected): Emit event when an item from suggestions is selected.

In the app.component.ts file add the following code

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'NgxTypeahead Demo';

  // Typeahead with Local Data List

  public myLocalList = [
    "Burgers",
    "Sandwiches",
    "French Fries",
    "Milkshakes",
    "Taco",
    "Biscuit",
    "Cookies",
    "Hot Dog",
    "Pizza",
    "Pancake"
  ];
  public search1 = '';
  selectedStatic(result) {
    this.search1 = result;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
//app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NgxTypeaheadModule } from 'ngx-typeahead';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxTypeaheadModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My own JSON object mimics the example except it's longer, that's all.

Comment: What is list in createListSource(list,...)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. D'oh!

```
   <input id="myList" name="mylist" formControlName="mylist" 
      typeahead]="mySuperCoolList" [isAnimated]="true" class="form-control"
      placeholder="Type an name from my SUPER COOL LIST" />
```

This works!
Added this as a FORM CONTROL in my list of FORM CONTROLS and WALA! TypeAhead WORKS!